# Python save .mp3 to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python on a Raspian (Raspberry pi) system I can successfully play and listen to a .mp3 file using the os.system() call with mpg123 and a valid URL.

How can I use Python to save the .mp3 file to disk instead of listen to it?

I can save it manually by right-clicking on the web page's Play button and selecting "Save video as...", but I don't know how to do that in a program.

Comment: The steps you need to follow are: 1) Open the page, 2) Parse the page, 3) Find the download link, 4) Use [urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) or similar to retrieve it... It's a bit of abroad question covering quite a few aspects though...

Answer (score 0):

I checked the manual page for `mp3123` here:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpg123

According to that page, you can specify an output file using the `-O` option or `--outfile`.

P.S. `os.system()` is a simple way to get started.  If you ever start getting frustrated by limitations of `os.system()`, such as not being able to capture the output or the error output, I suggest you use the `subprocess` module.  It's more complicated, but once you are used to it, it's easy to use... and it gives you full control over how your program executes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Raspberry pi version I have does not have a -O option.  I have a workaround using the -w option, which outputs a .wav file.  This will work for me. Thanks everyone for your help.